# How do you manage geolocation on mobile device? (Server side or Client-side/ permission management)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mobile, geolocation, geocoder

I'am working on app that ask geolocation to render data around a place. The location is asked with the first page is loaded.

I tried 2 approachs:

Server-side with the gem 'geocoder', it works on my PC but on Iphone and android is working sometimes (maybe due to the timeout ? i set the maximum value but it don't change anything)

```
  def localize
    @location = lookup_ip_location
    if @location.data["loc"].nil?
        @user.latitude = 48.49
        @user.longitude = -2.7
      else
        @user.latitude = @location.data['loc'].split(',').first.to_f
        @user.longitude = @location.data['loc'].split(',').second.to_f
    end
  end
```

Client-side with the script 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition' , it works on PC but on mobile device, it's random and i can't pinpoint the main issue. On Iphone, sometimes, i need to unlock some privacy setting, on Android, i don't know.

```
<div class="container">
<input type="text" id="latitude">
<input type="text" id="longitude">
</div>

    
<script>

    let latloc = document.getElementById('latitude');
    let lonloc = document.getElementById('longitude');

    var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };
    
    function error(err) {
      console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    }
    
    
    function setGeoCookie(position) {
      var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
      document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
      latloc.value = position.coords.latitude;
      lonloc.value = position.coords.longitude;
    }
    
    function getGeoLocation() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie, error, options);
    }
    
    getGeoLocation();
    
    </script>
```

How do you manage location (and permission if needed) on a Rails app ?

Thanks

Comment: Server-side geolocation is limited to IP based lookups which can be wildly inaccurate depending on the ISP. If the accuracy is in any way important you need to request the location from the user on the client side. Geocoder is really more useful for doing geospatial queries and reverse geocoding (looking up a location based on an address).

Comment: Beyond that there are some rather big problems with this question that make it unanswerable. You're vaguely hinting at some code with intermittent issues but your not actually showing your attempt at solving it. You're also asking multiple questions at once.

Comment: @max, i edited my questions with the ruby method that was called on my landing page. It didn't work so, as you mentionned it, i use a script client-side.

Comment: Where is the variable `latloc` coming from?

Comment: it's a variable used to display values in the html.

Comment: In Android, if the user has checked "high accuracy" in their location settings, your code should work. However, you have no control over that setting and if they didn't check it there's no way for you to enforce it. All you can do is inform them your app won't be precise without that option. Location accuracy is a broad subject. It's largely dependent on device hardware capabilities and it's not exactly easy to achieve consistently even when all required permissions are enabled. You still need a service to read multiple values across time and aggregate the last `n` results, excluding failures.

Comment: Here's an interesting read on the subject: https://www.gpsworld.com/how-to-achieve-1-meter-accuracy-in-android/.

Comment: Thanks both for your time. I display a complementary map where the user can choose a location and a arbitrary position for the worst case scenario.